# How do I sync a script over Photon Network in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, synchronization, photon

I have created a Game class which handles all transactions of a game (whose turn it is, what items each person has, etc). I would like to create one of these objects and keep it synced between both clients of a Photon Unity network.

First I tried Instantiating a prefab over the Photon network with InstantiateSceneObject() and then changing the attached script. The prefab is then found on both clients, but the attached game script is null on one of the players.

After that I tried adding the Game class to a Hashtable and then calling

```
 PhotonNetwork.room.SetCustomProperties(new ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable() { { "game", g } });
```

But when I attach my debugger to Unity, I notice the script hangs at this line. It doesn't move on to the next line of code.

I am really hoping I don't have to send every object of my game class as an RPC. Seems really tedious. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: InstantiateSceneObject() uses prefabs for object creation. It creates same objects on all clients with scripts which was attached to prefab during editing. Did you mean prefab when wrote "adding my script to a game object"?
Trying to set property to object which Photon can't serialize should cause error logging. Sending game objects over network does not make sense.
To synchronize Game object state between clients, you need to use RPC per property change or implement OnPhotonSerializeView with all properties you are interested in.

Comment: @photonians Yes that is what I meant. I have made corrections. I have not tried OnPhotonSerializeView, I will have to check that next. It doesn't make sense to me to make an RPC function for every property change. That Seems so tedious, since almost all of the properties are changed in between turns. Also no error logging, just hangs at that line